# Adding hotkey functionality in Openlayer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In my Openlayer based map application, I want to enable user to perform an action using a custom key combination.

How can this be done? Do I need to make use of ol.interaction.Interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you exactly expect but you will find below an answer according to my understanding.

Some interactions like `ol.interaction.Draw` already support default key combinations e.g http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.events.condition.html.

If you need custom combination of keys on existing interactions, these conditions functions act as a tiny wrapper on top of native JavaScript keyboard keys of your browser.
You need to create a new function that look more or less like [this excerpt function example](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.6.4/src/ol/events/condition.js#L17) from the OpenLayers code and adapt it to manage your own custom key combination.